# How to convert a plist file to text file automatically

Tags: xcode5, instruments

i am getting a .plist file after executing test cases(instruments) of an ios app, then how to convert it in text file to know about the status of test cases(Fail/Pass).

Comment: So the plist file is currently a binary?

Comment: no, its in a xml format type file which contains lot of data.

Comment: Errr, but XML is a type of text file, so you have no problem to solve.

Comment: actually i can change it in html or some other format by manually but it takes time, so i am looking for a tool which can simple take plist file as an input and convert it in .txt format and .txt file display only status of test cases either they are Fail or Pass with name of testcases.